# Proving set equivalence using laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove
$$
A∪B∪C = (A-B)∪(B-C)∪(C-A)∪(A∩B∩C)
$$
I have been able to prove it using venn diagram or just assigning elements, but have been so stuck with proving this by using existing laws.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with „by assigning elements“ and „by laws“? Sets are about elements, so I don’t know how or where you make a distinction...

Comment: I recommend starting with this simpler problem, it will give you an idea of how to do the given case: $A\cup B = (A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A \cap B)$

Comment: @prudiiarca I guess the OP means using laws like commutativity ($A \cup B = B \cup A$, $A \cap B = B \cap A$), associativity, distributivity, idempotence, etc., instead of proving that every element of the left hand side of the equation is a member of the right hand side and conversely.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin is true about the law. When it comes to assigning elements, I mean I assign arbitrary elements into all the sets above to try to see what the results are for both sides as it helps me understand the problem better.

Comment: @mathew and which simpler problem are you trying to point out? I have been working with this for some time so I think I'm just having a hard time at trying to look at other responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove this result using laws, it is more convenient to switch to the notation used in Boolean calculus: $XY$ for $X \cap Y$, $X + Y$ for $X \cup Y$ and $\bar X$ for the complement of $X$, $1$ for the universe and $0$ for the empty set. Now $X - Y$ is denoted by $X \bar Y$ (since $X - Y = X \cap Y^c$), and your formula becomes 
$$
A + B + C = A \bar B + B\bar C + C \bar A + ABC 
$$
Here is a list of the identities I will use:

1. Distributivity laws: $(X+Y)Z = XZ + XZ$ and $XY + Z = (X + Z)(Y + Z)$,
2. Idempotence laws: $X + X = X$, $XX = X$,
3. Commutativity laws: $X + Y = Y + X$ and $XY = YX$,
4. Associativity laws: $(X + Y) + Z = X + (Y + Z)$ and $(XY)Z = X(YZ)$,
5. Absorbing laws: $XX^c = 0$ and $X + X^c = 1$,
6. Neutral elements law: $X + 0 = X = 0 + X$ and $X1 = X = 1X$,
7. Complement laws: $\overline{\bar X} = X$, $\overline{XY} = \bar X + \bar Y$ and $\overline{X+Y} = \bar X \bar Y$.

Using these laws one gets successively
\begin{align}
&A \bar B + B\bar C + C \bar A + ABC \\
&\qquad= A \bar B(C + \bar C) + (A + \bar A)B\bar C + C \bar A(B + \bar B) + ABC \\
&\qquad= A \bar BC + A \bar B\bar C + AB\bar C + \bar A B\bar C + C \bar AB + C \bar A\bar B + ABC \\
&\qquad= (A \bar BC + A \bar B\bar C + AB\bar C + ABC) + (AB\bar C + \bar A B\bar C + C \bar AB  + ABC) + (A \bar BC + C \bar AB + C \bar A\bar B + ABC) \\
&\qquad= A(\bar BC +\bar B\bar C + B\bar C + BC) + B(A\bar C + \bar A\bar C + C \bar A  + AC) + C(A \bar B + \bar AB + \bar A\bar B + AB) \\
&\qquad= A(B + \bar B)(C + \bar C) + B(A + \bar A)(\bar C + C) + C(A + \bar A)(B +\bar B) \\
&\qquad= A+B+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$(A-B)\cup(B-C)\cup(C-A)\cup(A\cap B \cap C)$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')\cup(A\cap B \cap C)$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(A\cap B \cap C)\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$[A\cap (B'\cup(B\cap C))]\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$[A\cap((B'\cup B)\cap(B'\cup C))]\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$[A\cap\ (($ universal set $)\ \cap(B'\cup C))]\ \cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$[A\cap(B'\cup C)]\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap C')\cup(C\cap A')\cup(C\cap A)$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap C')\cup[C\cap(A'\cup A)$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap C')\cup[C\cap\ ($ universal set $)]\ $

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap C')\cup C$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup[(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup C')]$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup[(B\cup C)\cap\ ($ universal set $)\ ]$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup[(B\cup C)]$

---

=$(A\cap B')\cup B\cup C$

---

=$[(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup B')]\cup C$

---

=$[(A\cup B)\cap\ ($ universal set $)\ ]\cup C$

---

=$[(A\cup B)]\cup C$

---

=$A\cup B\cup C$

Answer (score 0):

We prove two inclusions, namely $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$. The latter follows immediately from the observation, that each thing on the right is contained in one of $A,B$ or $C$, so their union must be contained in $A\cup B \cup C$. For the converse we do a case distinction. By symmetry of the problem it suffices to show $A \subseteq $ RHS (right hand site) only.

Suppose $a \in A$. If $a \notin B$ we have $a \in A \setminus B$. Otherwise $a$ may also be in $C$, ie. $a \in A\cap B \cap C$ or not, ie. $a \in B \setminus C$. As $a$ was arbitrary we find $A\subseteq$ RHS.